# How to use a bootrap class as well as a CSS class

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How can I use 2 different classes? I have 2 HTML option fields when the user selects repair or another in the first one. Then the second must appear. But also its need a bootstrap class: form-control.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#correctiemaatregelen").on("change", function() {
            var select_val = $(this).val();
            console.log(select_val);
            if (select_val === 'Other') {
                $("#leveranciers").removeClass("hidden");
                document.getElementById("leveranciers");
            }
            else if (select_val === 'Repair') {
                $("#leveranciers").removeClass("hidden");
                document.getElementById("leveranciers");
            }
            else {
                $("#leveranciers").addClass("hidden");
                $("#leveranciers").val("");
            }
        });
    });
</script>

Correctie maatregelen:<br>
<select name="correctiemaatregelen" class="form-control" id="correctiemaatregelen" style="width: 300px">
    <option value="--Correctie maatregel--">--Correctie maatregel--</option>
    <option value="Use">Use</option>
    <option value="Repair">Repair</option>
    <option value="Return">Return</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
<br>
<select name="leveranciers" id="leveranciers" class="form-control hidden" style="width: 300px">
    <?php while ($row4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result4)):; ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row4['statusname'];?>"><?php echo $row4['statusname'];?></option>
    <?php endwhile;?>
</select>
```

Is there somebody that can help me with this (simple) problem?

Comment: Bad style of coding. Please use 'if (select_val === 'Other' || select_val === 'Repair')' in one if statement instead of multiple if-else statements.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just add another class to the element? If this causes problems you have to overwrite some Bootstrap styles with your own class

```js
$(function() {
    $("#correctiemaatregelen").on("change", function() {
        var select_val = $(this).val();
        console.log(select_val);
        if (select_val === "Other") {
            $("#leveranciers").removeClass("hidden");
            document.getElementById("leveranciers");
        }
        else if (select_val === "Repair") {
            $("#leveranciers").removeClass("hidden");
            $('#leveranciers').addClass("YOUR_CUSTOM_CLASS");
        }
        else {
            $("#leveranciers").addClass("hidden");
            $("#leveranciers").val("");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<select name="leveranciers" id="leveranciers" class="form-control YOUR_CUSTOM_CLASS hidden" style="width: 300px">
    <?php while ($row4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result4)):; ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row4['statusname'];?>"><?php echo $row4['statusname'];?></option>
    <?php endwhile;?>
</select>
```

Comment: how to add that class to my jQuery?

Comment: I added the code to my example. Not sure if the else-if-statement is the correct position, but you can use it anywhere necessary. You already use the addClass method in your code